# Set spring resources folder base path

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to add my application name as the resources folder base path

```
# For example, from
http://localhost:8081/1/imgs/someImage.jpg  
http://localhost:8081/1/css/common.css

# to 
http://localhost:8081/myAppName/1/imgs/someImage.jpg  
http://localhost:8081/myAppName/1/css/common.css

# with some spring resources configuration in application.properties
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.version=1
```

How can I set it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by customising the `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` property, eg.:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/myName/**
```

This is also mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

> By default, resources are mapped on `/**` but you can tune that via `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`. For instance, relocating all resources to `/resources/**` can be achieved as follows:
>
> ```
> spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
> ```